# How to select multiple variables from a dropdown menu in Selenium (python)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I would like to automatically download different datasets from the Climate World Bank (https://climateknowledgeportal.worldbank.org/download-data)

I would like to create a couple of for loops in order to iterate along the countries and along their subregions.

[image]

This is an example of a dataset to download.

However, I have two major problems:

1. I am not able to select the values from the drop-down menu if a change to the timeseries tab
2. I do not know how to select the values for subnational unit since it exist only after sub-national units is chosen for area type.

This is the code that I have written until now

```
from multiprocessing import Value
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import os 



wd = webdriver.Chrome('C:/Users/alber/OneDrive/Desktop/UniTn/WebD/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe')
url = "https://climateknowledgeportal.worldbank.org/download-data"
wd.get(url)

download_b = wd.find_element(By.ID,'ncfile')
tab = wd.find_element(by = By.XPATH , value = '//*[@id="data-download-form-container"]/div/ul/li[3]/a')
tab.click()

#WebDriverWait(wd, 15).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "variable")))

select = Select(wd.find_element(by = By.ID, value = "variable"))
select.select_by_visible_text("Mean-Temperature")

select = Select(wd.find_element(by = By.ID, value = "aggregation"))
select.select_by_visible_text("Monthly")

select = Select(wd.find_element(by = By.ID, value = "type"))
select.select_by_visible_text("Sub-national units")
select = Select(wd.find_element(by = By.ID, value = "country"))
select.select_by_visible_text("Italy")
select = Select(wd.find_element(by = By.ID, value = "timeperiod"))
select.select_by_visible_text("1901 - 2021")
download_b.click()
```

Thank you for your help.